# Use SQL Server LocalDB with multi user over local network

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I developed a WPF application that uses a SQL Server database and my client wants to use it with multiple users. I don't know a lot about networking and server domains, so can someone please tell me how to set up SQL Server for multiple users with Windows authentication? And also is SQL Server LocalDB an option, can LocalDB be connected from another computer?

Thanks

Comment: Directly from the tag of localdb > `It is not not intended for multi-user scenarios`

Comment: `LocalDB` is a **developer only** story - if you need to support multiple concurrent users - get a **real** SQL Server and install it on a central server

Comment: SQL Server documentation tells you how to set it up for multiple users with Windows authentication. This is not a "please write a tutorial for me" site. As far as LocalDB, it's for local (development) use and not for general network/multi-user use.

Comment: ok thanks for every one